# Why is my nav bar not the whole width of the browser with my current codes?

Tags: css, center

With the CSS code posted below, I thought that I would be making a nav bar that extends the width of the browser and has a red background. I also thought I would be making the logo for the page appear ont he far left, with the text immediately to the right. What do I need to do to make a #ff0000 nav bar extend the whole width of the browser? How can I align this text to be to the right of the logo and at the top of the browser window?

Here is the CSS code:

```
.logo{
    float:left
            }

.titletext {
    text-align: right;
            }


nav {
    display: table;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    }
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<DOCCTYPE = HTML>

<html>
<head>
    <div class="titletext">
       <h2>Penguin NetOPS Solutions</h2> 
       <h3>IT Repair</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="http://www.logodesignlove.com/images/classic/penguin-logo.jpg" alt="Mountain        View" style="width:200px;height:200px">
     </div>


<nav>
    <a href= "/~team_21/about_us.html">About Us</a> |
    <a href= "/~team_21/cgi-bin/loan_calculator.cgi">Calculate Loan Payments</a>|
    <a href= "/~team_21/cgi-bin/credit_check.cgi">Credit Check</a> |
    <a href= "/~team_21/contact_us.html">Contact Us</a>|
    <a href= "/~team_21/lottery.html">Special Offer</a>

</nav>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Just add `float: right;` to the `.titletext` class. See http://jsfiddle.net/xzfs5ny1/

Comment: Also, `<DOCCTYPE = HTML>` is wrong. Replace with `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: Why is your code in the head section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/usd7v82v/1/)**

Never write code inside the `<head>` tag, you should use `float:right` for `.titletext`

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div class="titletext">
   <h2>Penguin NetOPS Solutions</h2> 
   <h3>IT Repair</h3>
</div>
<div class="logo">
  <img src="http://www.logodesignlove.com/images/classic/penguin-logo.jpg" alt="Mountain        View" style="width:200px;height:200px">
 </div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>

<nav>
    <a href= "/~team_21/about_us.html">About Us</a> |
        <a href= "/~team_21/cgi-bin/loan_calculator.cgi">Calculate Loan Payments</a>|
        <a href= "/~team_21/cgi-bin/credit_check.cgi">Credit Check</a> |
        <a href= "/~team_21/contact_us.html">Contact Us</a>|
        <a href= "/~team_21/lottery.html">Special Offer</a>

    </nav>
        </body>
```

**CSS**

```
     .clearfix
        {
        clear:both;
        }
        .logo{
                float:left
        }
        .titletext {
            float: right;
        }
        nav {
            display: table;
            width:100%;
            background-color: #ff0000;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is not valid. You insert content into head tag.

Check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kapantzak/f49LttLs/)

```
<head>
    <title>Your title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Place here your content -->
    <div class="titletext">
   <h2>Penguin NetOPS Solutions</h2> 
   <h3>IT Repair</h3>
</div>
<div class="logo">
  <img src="http://www.logodesignlove.com/images/classic/penguin-logo.jpg" alt="Mountain        View" style="width:200px;height:200px">
 </div>


<nav>
<a href= "/~team_21/about_us.html">About Us</a> |
<a href= "/~team_21/cgi-bin/loan_calculator.cgi">Calculate Loan Payments</a>|
<a href= "/~team_21/cgi-bin/credit_check.cgi">Credit Check</a> |
<a href= "/~team_21/contact_us.html">Contact Us</a>|
<a href= "/~team_21/lottery.html">Special Offer</a>

</nav>
</body>
```